# Monero MalwareBytes Blocked IP Address

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I run Malwarebytes and I consistently get this error message when I run Monero Gui Wallet.

Malwarebytes
www.malwarebytes.com

-Log Details-
Protection Event Date: 2/18/17
Protection Event Time: 10:05 AM
Logfile: 
Administrator: Yes

-Software Information-
Version: 3.0.6.1469
Components Version: 1.0.50
Update Package Version: 1.0.1295
License: Premium

-System Information-
OS: Windows 10
CPU: x64
File System: NTFS
User: System

-Blocked Website Details-
Malicious Website: 1
, , Blocked, [-1], [-1],0.0.0

-Website Data-
Domain: 
IP Address: 94.102.53.209
Port: [18019]
Type: Outbound
File: C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\monero-wallet-gui\monerod.exe

Should I add this IP address as a trusted entry in Malwarebytes?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Abuse IP DB](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/94.102.53.209), this IP has been involved in hacking and spam attempts several times. This could be also a dynamic IP used by DSL subscribers. However, it should be save to whitelist all outgoing connections for monerod, since it only syncs with the monero network and shouldn't be able to download any executable code (unless there is a serious security flaw in monerod itself).